# Como evitar que se duplique un Activity de Android

Tags: android, activity

Actualmente estoy trabajando con un POS WEB que incluye el escaneo de código de barras. Para esto el POS esta en un `WebView`, y cuando le doy clic al botón para leer el código de barras codifico la url para mandar llamar el `activity` del lector de código de barras, ya que este es nativo de Android.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ibtnRefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            showPB();
            if(!url.contains("sendScanReader"))
            {
            }else if(!url.contains("Settings")) {

            }else{
                view.loadUrl(Common.getURL());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Carga Finalizada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hidePB();
            if(url.contains("sendScanReader"))
            {
                hidePB();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i,100);

            }else if(url.contains("vta")){...
```

El problema radica en que al parecer Main2Activity (que es el activity de lectura) se abre 2 veces. Asi que cuando hago el proceso para el handleResult, se "cierra" el lector, pero la app me muestra nuevamente el activity.

Este el el HandleResult del activity lector

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    // Do something with the result here
    Log.v("main", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
    Log.v("main", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)

    String newURL = Common.getURL()+"?"+rawResult.getText();
    Common.setURL(newURL);

    mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
    mScannerView = null;
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main.class);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
}
```

Aqui el fragmento del manifest. Ya intente tambien con singleInstance pero no me da resultado.

```
<activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Edit:

Agrego el codigo de showPB() y hidePb() para evitar posibles confusiones.

```
public void showPB(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

public void  hidePB(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Funcion para ocultar PB",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Que es hidePB() y showPB() ?

Comment: son funciones para ocultar y mostrar un progressbar segun se requiera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quedo resuelto. Lo que hice fue simplemente agregarle flags a mi Intent.

```
@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Carga Finalizada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        hidePB();
        if(url.contains("sendScanReader"))
        {
            hidePB();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //esta es la linea nueva con la que evito los duplicados.
            startActivityForResult(i,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

En `onPageFinished()` realizas el Intent para abrir `Main2Activity`, recuerda que el método `onPageFinished()` se llama al finalizar la carga de la página dentro del `WebView`.

**El problema que mencionas puede surgir si cargas más de una ocasión una url dentro de un `WebView`.**

Tanto `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` como `onLoadResource()` estan realizando la carga de la url dentro del `WebView` mediante:

```
view.loadUrl(...);
```